# get whole page css with styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to build something like [this](https://tailwindui.com/components/) but I have problem with building iframes.

when I pass them html via `srcdoc=` that also needs styling, so I am able to pass my CDN link but that is not good solution, because it fetches that link in every render new iframe.

I wanted to get all CSS classes with all style rules to pass it in `<style></style>` but it still looks ugly. **What do I need?**

**HTML** markup

```
<div class="relative z-10" aria-labelledby="modal-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">
  <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-200 opacity-75"></div>
  <div class="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto">
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full">
      <div class="bg-white p-5 px-10 rounded-[1rem] max-w-xs">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h5 class="font-bold text-xl my-2 text-gray-700">
            Exit
          </h5>
          <p class="text-sm font-normal text-gray-500">
            Click the "confirm" button to close the window without saving
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 text-center mt-3">
          <div class="col-span-1">
            <button class="w-full p-2 bg-gray-100 font-bold text-sm rounded-md text-gray-400">Cancel</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-span-1">
            <button class="w-full p-2 bg-blue-600 font-bold text-sm rounded-md text-gray-100">Confirm</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS** Methods

Get style rules from css class

```
function getStyle(className) {
    var cssText = "";
    var classes = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
    for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {        
        if (classes[x].selectorText == className) {
            cssText += classes[x].cssText || classes[x].style.cssText;
        }         
    }
    return cssText;
}
```

Get All class that is used on page

```
[].concat(...[...document.querySelectorAll('*')].map(e=>[...e.classList])).filter((d,i,a)=>a.indexOf(d)==i).sort().map(i=> getStyle('.'+i)).join(' ');
```

**I have This**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6K9e.png)

**I do This**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irBCY.png)

**I get This**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc1qM.png)

I think I need to get tag classes but that is not enough, my JS code needs some update.

Comment: So you are trying to get all the classes on the HTML file, correct?

Comment: @OfficerErikK No, not all. Imagine you have only that HTML in your project and then you run npm run build. So I need all these css classes that is builded for that html.

Comment: Then what are you trying to do, as, for some reason, I can't really follow what your asking? Though I believe that I now know what you want, you want to convert the classes to create the styling for each element, correct?

Comment: @OfficerErikK Please check images. I am not getting enough css classes with that code, so I finish up with ugly looking markup.

Comment: The images don't show me anything of importance, after all, for one, I don't know what you want. You haven't told us what you want help with, that is what I am trying to find out. So give me some context, explain your problem in some more detail.

Comment: As you see the first image and the last (result) are very different. because by that js code I am not getting enough classes from that markup. so my question why I miss, why is not it enough. Please if you still don't not get it try it on codepen with tailwind cdn if you are interested.